# Plotly Python Sort Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a large data table in Plotly that I have created and I would like to sort by one of the columns after the table has been built. I haven't found any documentation on this. Using the simple example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
             cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                 ])
fig.show()
```

Is it possible to short the resulting `go.Table`  object or `go.Figure` object by the "B Scores" column before displaying it? Or do the table values need to be correctly sorted before building the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming requirement is for it to be interactive,  you can use **updatemenus**,  where data is replaced with sorted data.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

v = [[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]
df = pd.DataFrame(v).T.sort_values(0).T

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=["A Scores", "B Scores"]), cells={"values": df.values})]
)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "label": b["l"],
                    "args": [{"cells": {"values": df.T.sort_values(b["c"]).T.values}},[0],],
                }
                for b in [{"l": "A Scores", "c": 0}, {"l": "B Scores", "c": 1}]
            ],
            "direction": "down",
            "y": 1,
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: hi Rob, maybe I doing something wrong, but the dropdown doesn't change anything me. Any thoughts?

Comment: either way, creating the DataFrame. transposing, sorting, and transposing still solves my problem for a static table. Will accept. Thanks